# Resnet vanishing gradient

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, resnet

In very deep neural networks, the weights in the earlier layers sometimes don't get updated. So compared to shallow networks, these networks have a higher loss. Why doesn't the weights in the earlier layers get updated?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is called "the vanishing gradients problem" and has been around for a while.  I recommend you search for it as it has likely been answered well.

Comment: [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-vanishing-gradient-problem-69bf08b15484) could help